# How do I get current client sort and filter settings from a DevExpress MVCxGridView grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a simple DevExpress ASP.MVC GridView and I would like to produce a PDF export of the data in the grid. I have worked out how to produce an export of all the data, but I'd like to be able to only export data that appears in the grid. This will allow users to sort and filter data and only have that data appear in the export.

The sorting and filtering all appears to happen client side and I've searched the DevExpess documentation and inspected the client side grid object and cannot find the information I need. I've also tried handling the grid's client side events. The only success I've had here is by handling the `ColumnSorting` event. Using this I can record each sort as it happens, but this does not tell me what direction the sort is in, and whether the sort is applied solely to the column provided in the event or to that column as part of a multiple column sort.

The only option I have left is to use additional form controls external to the grid to control the sorting and filtering. I'd really rather not do this as my client is very keen on the built-in sorting and filtering functionality.

Please can somebody tell me how I can capture the current sorting and filtering settings applied by the user so I can pass them to the controller action that will produce the PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out by seeing some code in one of the DevExpress samples:

http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/Editing

In the code for the Grid's partial view is the following:

```
settings.ClientLayout = (s, e) =>
{
    if(e.LayoutMode == ClientLayoutMode.Loading) {
        if(Session["GridState"] != null)
            e.LayoutData = (string)Session["GridState"];
    }
    else
        Session["GridState"] = e.LayoutData;
};
```

By storing the `LayoutData` in the session state it can be applied, using the same code, to the `GridViewSettings` used to produce the PDF export. This resolves my issue, but I'm not sure how generally useful this is, as the `LayoutData` would have to be parsed due to it being in a format similar to the following:

```
page1|sort1|a0|filter[Title] Like '%Test%'|conditions1|1|3|visible9|t0|t1|t2|t3|t4|t5|t6|t7|t8|width9|e|e|e|e|e|e|e|e|e
```